# save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' in django

Tags: django

I create a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    present_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
               settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
               related_name='member_persons')
```

forms.py:

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)

    def save(self, request, commit=True):
         person = super().save(commit=False)
         if not person.pk:
             person.user = get_user(request)
         if commit:
             person.save()
             self.save_m2m()
         return person
```

It worked fine for first person create. When same person again try to submit create form with different data it gives 'save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request''. Full traceback:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  217.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  162.         self.object = form.save()

Exception Type: TypeError at /person/create/
Exception Value: save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

my views.py:

```
@require_authenticated_permission(
'member.add_person')
class PersonCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
    model = Person
    success_url = '/person/'
    form_class = MemberForm
```

I want to show a message "You already submitted data" rather than getting this error. How can I show this message in the person creation form?
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

New error:

Traceback:

```
File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  213.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  174.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_context_data
  93.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "/home/ohid/test_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form
  45.         return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

Exception Type: TypeError at /person/create/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

Answer (score 4):

`save` signatrue is invalid. there shouldn't be `request` in arguments. if you want to pass it to form use `get_form`

```
@require_authenticated_permission('member.add_person')
class PersonCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
    model = Person
    success_url = '/person/'
    form_class = MemberForm

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.request = self.request
        return form
```

And then

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
         person = super().save(commit=False)
         if not person.pk:
             person.user = get_user(self.request)
         if commit:
             person.save()
             self.save_m2m()
         return person
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It gives new error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'. I added full traceback in my main question.

Comment: @djpro use `get_form` instead then. See updated answer.

Comment: It gives 'IntegrityError at /person/create/

UNIQUE constraint failed: member_person.user_id' when I tried to submit data from same logged in user.

Comment: @djpro  This is entirely different problem. it because there is already is `Person` object with this user.. It is related to your model structure.

Comment: In traceback it mentioned /home/ohid/test_venv/persontest/member/forms.py in save

                person.save()
is causes this error

Comment: @djpro I would suggest creating separate question for this. Because it is not related to current one.

Answer (score 1):

I send those parameters in this way

```
class MemberNew(generic.CreateView):

    model = Member
    form_class = MemberForm
    template_name = "..."

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        return MemberForm(self.request, **self.get_form_kwargs())
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this type of error can occur when you forget to add parameteres in save function in function "perform create" in View.:

```
# views.py
class UserRegisterView(CreateAPIView):
  def get_queryset(self):
      return User.objects.all()
   
  def get_serializer_class(self):
      return user_serializers.CustomUserRegisterSerializer

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
      serializer.save(self.request)
```